# Filtering and adjusting data table

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am attempting to display a dataframe with multiple `pickerInput` variables. When filtering by one variable, in the following example, species, it works fine. However, I can't seem to figure out how to format the sub setting code when trying to filter the dataframe by a second (and eventually a third variable)

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

results <- iris
results$Species <- as.character(results$Species)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel(
    h1("Iris Table", align="center")
  ),
  
  fluidRow( 
    # column(3, 
     #      pickerInput("sepal_width_input", "Sepal", choices = results$Sepal.Width, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), selected=NULL, multiple=TRUE)),
    
    column(3,
           pickerInput("speciesInput", "Species", choices=unique(results$Species), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), selected=NULL, multiple=TRUE)
    ),
    column(9, 
           DT::dataTableOutput('table')))
  
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  mydata <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$speciesInput)) {df <- results
    } else df <- results[results$Species %in% input$speciesInput,]
    df
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(mydata())
  )
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I included a second pickerInput behind a hashtag. Can someone tell me how the following code snippet should be formatted when including both variables?

```
mydata <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$speciesInput)) {df <- results
        } else df <- results[results$Species %in% input$speciesInput,]
        df
      })
```

Comment: I think you mean to load `library(DT)` instead of `library(data.table)`?  You use the former, but do not use the latter. My answer also includes this minor edit to the libraries imported

Comment: I think this would work really well, the only issue is that my actual code is set up to upload a csv into the app. I hope to avoid having the user needing to do anything outside of the app (in this case that would be assigning the data frame in question to 'results' in the filter_data function that you provided. Can that function just be moved into the ui?- might be a topic for a separate question though

Comment: why not just pass the data to the function, along with the inputs?.  That is, change the `filter_data()` signature to `function(df, spec=NULL, sepw=NULL)`, and use `df` in the function instead of `results`.  Then in the reactive, you can simply do `filter_data(user_csv(), input$speciesInput, input$sepal_width_input)`

Comment: Thanks so much, @langtang! Very new to shiny so this is really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a function that handles the filtering, and pass the inputs to that function, like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

results <- iris
results$Species <- as.character(results$Species)

filter_data <- function(spec=NULL, sepw=NULL) {
  res <- results
  if(!is.null(spec)) res <- res %>% dplyr::filter(Species %in% spec)
  if(!is.null(sepw)) res <- res %>% dplyr::filter(Sepal.Width %in% sepw)
  return(res)
}

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel(
    h1("Iris Table", align="center")
  ),
  
  fluidRow( 
    column(3, 
          pickerInput("sepal_width_input", "SepalWidth", choices = results$Sepal.Width, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), selected=NULL, multiple=TRUE)),
    
    column(3,
           pickerInput("speciesInput", "Species", choices=unique(results$Species), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), selected=NULL, multiple=TRUE)
    ),
    column(9, 
           DT::dataTableOutput('table')))
  
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  mydata <- reactive({
    filter_data(input$speciesInput, input$sepal_width_input)
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(mydata())
  )
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```